# Better than brute-force way to find the "lowest" sha1 hash?

Tags: cryptography, brute-force

While pointing out a SQL injection flaw on another question, I was able to show that an arbitrary sha1 hash could be inserted into a query such that it would be taken for a real hash, and was therefore able to login assuming the dummy hash was used. I could inject an `ORDER BY` but then wanted to make sure the hash I was using as an example was likely to come out at the top.

From my understanding, `0000000...0` should be a valid *possible* output from the hash function but, of course, finding the associated input is non-trivial.

In any case, it got me wondering. Is there any way - except brute force or downloading a rainbow table  - to find a hash that would sort before an arbitrary point (say before 99% of passwords =~ in the first 1.46150x10^46)

I suspect the answer is no but would like confirmation.

Comment: Perhaps better suited at [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) since no programming is involved.

Comment: Bitcoin mining is very similar to this: The goal it to find an `x`  for which `SHA256(SHA256(x))` starts with enough leading zero bits.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Fascinating. I never took the time to look intop what bitcoin was doing under the hood. Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a method faster than brute force, it represents a weakness in the hash function.  Essentially what you're looking for is a modified [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), just for a group of hash values rather than a single value.

Comment: From the link... "By definition, an ideal hash function is such that the fastest way to compute a first or second preimage is through a brute force attack". That pretty much hits the nail on the head. Thanks for the reference.